# django-otp: should I increment the counter when generating hotp token?

Tags: python, security, token, hmac

I use django-otp to generate hotp,
I not yet found the docs to properly generate hotp token

so I read from the `verify_token` method in `HOTPDevice` model class, found out how to verify the token

```
if hotp(key, counter, self.digits) == token:
    verified = True
    self.counter = counter + 1
    self.save()
```

from the above I know that I can create the token using `hotp` function.

So then I use hotp function to generate the token, but I notice it repeatedly returns the same token when it's not confirmed. So should I increment the `counter` too when generating it?

source: [HOTPDevice source from django-otp](https://bitbucket.org/psagers/django-otp/src/2e5e1a3813258d9fb99c6f572b9451ad4967b533/django-otp/django_otp/plugins/otp_hotp/models.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found quote from [RFC 4226 - HOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226#section-7.2),

> The HOTP client (hardware or software token) increments its counter
> and then calculates the next HOTP value HOTP client

So I should increment the `counter` first, save it to the object, and then returns the generated token